# Kafka partition offsets are unevenly distributed by significant amount

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a scenario in one of our testing environments after a load test where our kafka partition's offsets were unevenly distributed. If it was off by a couple of hundreds, I'd consider that to be normal, but this seems to be different.

Amongst 10 partitions, I am seeing the following distribution across our partitions:

```
-------------------------
|partition  |     offset|
-------------------------
|0          |    100000+|
-------------------------
|1          |       ~200|
-------------------------
|2 - 10     |        ~50|
-------------------------
...
```

The load test generated unique keys and assigned them to the events that were generated. According to the kafka docs, as long as the keys are not identical they should randomly pick a partition. It seems odd to me that the offset is so high for the first partition and was wondering if anyone has any knowledge as to why this occurs?

This does not seem to occur to such a degree in normal circumstances, only when a load test is performed.

[Edit]: Only producer configs are related to SSL settings. Everything else is default. The `key` is generated using `uuid/v4` during the load test.

```
{
  host: process.env.KAFKA_URL,
  requestTimeout: 1000,
  ssl: true,
  sslOptions: config.sslOptions
}
```

Comment: Can you add your Producer config used by the test and show how the keys are generated?

Comment: @NicPegg Updated, the configs are mostly defaults aside from the ssl related properties. The ID is generated with `uuid/v4`, did a quick check in the consumer logs to confirm there are no duplicates of these IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to the kafka docs, as long as the keys are not identical they should randomly pick a partition.

The logic for the `DefaultPartitioner` class is more something like

```
hash(key) % numberOfPartitions
```

as the [code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3fdf1523a369e9e2f03e215f39c0ed987b2a16c5/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java#L71) is written.

It looks like your keys mostly fall into partition `0` and might be worth re-considering key creation and/or selection of another partitioner strategy.

In case you really want to have partition selected round-robin you can use `null` keys.

Answer (score 0):

There are two dependencies on partition selection by going with the key:

1. If the producer provides the same key for each message record, hashing will give you the same hash number, but it doesn’t ensure that if you provide two different keys, then it will never give you the same hash number.
2. The default partitioner uses the hash value of the key and the total number of partitions on a topic to determine the partition number. If you increase a partition number, then the default partitioner will return different numbers evenly if you provide the same key. Its explained here: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-producer-internals-DefaultPartitioner.html

Also -> https://www.learningjournal.guru/courses/kafka/kafka-foundation-training/custom-partitioner/